# Invocation of structure member info display function spits garbled characters

Tags: c, struct

I created a structure that goes as follows:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char name[20];
    char country[20];
    int age;
    float height;
} details;
```

Accompanying the structure definition are two functions that accept and display the details of the structure's members respectively:

```
void enter_details(details d1)
{
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    gets(d1.name);
    printf("Enter your country: ");
    gets(d1.country);
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d",&d1.age);
    printf("Enter your height (in meters): ");
    scanf("%d",&d1.height);
}

void show_details(details d1)
{
    printf("Name: ");
    puts(d1.name);
    printf("\nCountry: ");
    puts(d1.country);
    printf("\nAge: %d",d1.age);
    printf("\nHeight: %.2f m",d1.height);
}
```

The declaration of a structure object in the main() segment is relatively straightforward and goes as follows:

```
details d1;
```

While the compiler doesn't spit any errors as such, and neither does the invocation of the function that accepts information for the structure's members, invocation of the show_details() function spits out nothing but garbled, gibberish characters. What is causing this anomaly?

Comment: Structures are passed by value, not by reference. So `enter_details()` updates a copy of the structure from `main()`. You need to pass a pointer to the structure.

Comment: @LordObnoxious explainded in my answer

Comment: @Barmar isn't that precisely the structure variable whose members I am trying to update and display though? Why should that entail an error?

Comment: No. The structure `d1` in `enter_details()` is a different one from the one in `main()`. You get an error because you never initialized the structure in `main()`.

Comment: @Barmar but I did. Check the latter half of my post. I declared the structure `d1` of type `details` in the `main()` section, and this is precisely the structure variable I passed to both of the functions.

Comment: Do you understand what the word "copy" means?

Comment: @Barmar in this context, yes. But the contention lies in determining as to why the function will create a local "in-function" copy of the structure variable and pass on the values to them despite the fact that I used the dot operator to specifically refer to its members. Why is that so?

Comment: Except for arrays, all function parameters are passed as copies. Nothing you do to the in-function copy affects the caller's copy. The dot operator is irrelevant, it's being used to update the in-function copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, arguments of a function are passed by *value*, **not** by *reference*, meaning that the argument you pass will be copied. So what you are dealing with inside your function is a copy of your object, not the actual object. In order to refer to the actual object, you need to pass a *reference*.

Also, avoid using `scanf()` (and `gets()`) to read input. Use `fgets()` instead.

So, you should change your code to:

```c
void enter_details(details *d1)
{
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    getstring(d1->name, sizeof(d1->name)));

    printf("Enter your country: ");
    getstring(d1->country, sizeof(d1->country));

    printf("Enter your age: ");
    getint(&d1->age);

    printf("Enter your height (in meters): ");
    getint(&d1->height);
}
```

---

An alternative to `scanf()` to read a string:

```c
char *getstring(char *str, int size)
{
    if (!fgets(str, size, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; // fgets() reads the ending '\n' so null-terminate the string
    return str;
}
```

And to read an `int`:

```c
int getint(int *i)
{
    char buffer[255];
    if (!fgets(buffer, 255, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
    
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", i) != 1)
        return 0;
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why should one avoid using scanf() and gets() though?

Comment: You should definitely avoid using `gets()`. It doesn't have any buffer size limit, and has been removed from the language. I downvoted because of this.

Comment: @Barmar It's his code not mine. He should definitely not use `gets()` and `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use gets. Use `fgets` instead.  `fgets(d1.name, sizeof(d1.name), stdin);`
2. You need to pass the reference to the struct otherwise you will work on the local copy of the structure. You can also return the structure.

```
void enter_details1(details *d1)
{
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(d1 -> name, sizeof(d1 ->name), stdin);
    printf("Enter your country: ");
    fgets(d1 -> country, sizeof(d1 -> country), stdin);
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d",&d1 ->age);
    printf("Enter your height (in meters): ");
    scanf("%d",&d1 ->height);
}

details enter_details(void)
{
    details d1;
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(d1.name, sizeof(d1.name), stdin);
    printf("Enter your country: ");
    fgets(d1.country, sizeof(d1.country), stdin);
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d",&d1.age);
    printf("Enter your height (in meters): ");
    scanf("%d",&d1.height);
    retunrn d1;
}
```

usage:

```
int main(void)
{
     details d;
     enter_details1(&d);

     //or

     d = enter_details();
     
     /* .... */ 
}
```

BTW I hope that you know that `height` can be only entered in full meters. No fractions

Comment: `gets(d1 -> country, sizeof(d1 -> country), stdin);` should be `fgets(d1 -> country, sizeof(d1 -> country), stdin);`.

Comment: You need to remove the newline after using `fgets()`

Comment: @0___________ apropos "you need to pass the reference to the struct otherwise you will work on the local copy of the structure": hold on, isn't the function accepting the copy of the structure declared in main? Moreover, why would the values not change, considering the fact that the function accesses individual members of the said copy of the structure using the dot operator?

Comment: "isn't the function accepting the copy of the structure declared in main?" - Yes it is. The thing here is "copy", not the **actual** structure.

"why would the values not change...?" They change in the copy, not in the structure in your calling function.

Comment: @0___________ apropos this statement of yours "BTW I hope that you know that height can be only entered in full meters. No fractions," why is this applicable? I've declared the height variable of the float type. Why would that warrant an error?

Comment: @LordObnoxious so you have another error in your code: `scanf("%d",&d1.height);`